Wordpress Plugins failing to update and unable to access parts of the admin
I have a website built on the CherryFramework and having an issue accessing admin areas and updating plugins.
I get the error color value: failed at nation.less"; /home/pianomanscholars/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme53095/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less on line 44
I've tried updating all plugins, checking for support documents but I can't even access the Cherry options
I've also disabled all the plugins and switching the theme
